# Disable autocomplete in CakePHP form input box

Tags: forms, cakephp

I am creating form inputs with the CakePHP Form helper and some inputs (Most of the time 'username' and 'password') are being autocompleted on create actions, login actions, etc.. this is annoying. I am guessing those are just more common so the browser is using its cookies to try to complete the inputs.

Anyways.. how do I disable this?

In my view:

```
...

echo $this->Form->input('username', array(
    'label' => 'Please enter your username',
    'class' => 'pure-u-1-2'
));
echo $this->Form->input('password', array(
    'label' => 'Please enter your password',
    'class' => 'pure-u-1-2'
));

...
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Not marking as duplicate because you are asking for cakephp, but reading this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag and basic cake doc should have done it for you.

Comment: Right, but I wanted a quick reference for CakePHP users in this situation. Back when I was beginning cake I struggled with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify attributes to be sent to the form helper. Specify the attribute 'autocomplete' and set its value to 'off'.

```
...

echo $this->Form->input('username', array(
    'label' => 'Please enter your username',
    'class' => 'pure-u-1-2',
    'autocomplete' => 'off'
));
echo $this->Form->input('password', array(
    'label' => 'Please enter your password',
    'class' => 'pure-u-1-2',
    'autocomplete' => 'off'
));

...
```

Which results in something like this for your HTML:

```
<input name="data[Model][username]" autocomplete="off" class="pure-u-1-2" id="ModelUsername" type="text">
```

You may also do this on the whole form instead of just each input. Just specify the same attribute and value in the form create like so:

```
...

echo $this->Form->create('Model', array(
    'class' => 'class',
    'autocomplete' => 'off'
));
```

This will give you something like this in your HTML:

```
<form action=".../Model/Action" class="class" autocomplete="off" id="ModelActionForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

**NOTE** Several browsers will now ignore autocomplete="off" or autocomplete="false". The workaround is to place a hidden text and password field before all other inputs on your form. The browsers will fill those instead of the ones you want to leave alone.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution is to use autocomplete = new-password

It works great in Chrome and Firefox

Like this:

```
$this->Form->input('password', array('type' => 'password', 'autocomplete' => 'new-password'));
```